# Filter elements from related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: Here are my tables]

I'm currently displaying on my homepage all Current Bets (`current` is an option of `status` attribute) from all members. Here is my code:

```
<% @bets.where(status: "Current").each do |bet| %>
<%= bet.match_name %>
<%= bet.bet_choice %>
<% end %>
```

(where @bets = Bet.all in my Page controller)

What I would like to do is to display on my homepage all Current bets from members who are in the "team" (team is a boolean in User).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that, you have proper associations defined in your `User` and `Bet` models.

Try something like this:

```
User.where(team: true).joins(:bets).where('bets.status' => 'Current')
```

#### Update_1:

I see you have a column `id_user` in your `bets` table, which should be `user_id` instead, assuming your associations are like: `User` *has_many* `bets` and `Bet` *belongs_to* `User`.

#### Update_2:

If you want all such `bets` and then loop through the `bets` collection, then you have to modify the above query little bit like this:

```
Bet.where(status: "Current").joins(:user).where('users.team' => 'true')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering :)
Yes, my associations were good in my models.

I tried your code but it's displaying nothing. Why do you start by User since elements I want to display are bets ?

Comment: I did not test the code first. I just wrote guideline of how it should be. But, yeah, I noticed that you wanted the `bets` so all you needed to tweak the query a bit. However, I updated the answer. If you think it helped you to reach to correct solution, please consider accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code :

```
<% Bet.where(status: "Current").joins(:user).where('users.team' => 'true').each do |bet| %>
```

Thanks for the "joins" tip KM. It helped me well.